# is there any way to deploy 2 angular applications on nginx on same port?

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to deploy 2 angular applications on nginx server on same port and and those will be separted with /app1 and /app2

I understand that it works with different base url approach `<base href=/app1` and `<base href=/app2`

is there any other way of achieving it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/)   to route the request based on url, for example

```
frontend http
acl app1 path_beg -i /app1
acl app2 path_beg -i /app2


use_backend app1_path    if app1
use_backend app2_path    if app2


backend app1_path
  balance roundrobin 
  // can have multiple docker containers here
  server app1_path_1 127.0.0.1:4000 
  server app1_path_2 127.0.0.1:4001

backend app2_path
  balance roundrobin
  server app2_path_1 127.0.0.1:5000
  server app2_path_2 127.0.0.1:5001
```